# Bluetooth device maintains connection even after passkey (PIN) change

Tags: bluetooth

I am using a SPP Bluetooth module to send data between my Android phone app and the module. I stumbled upon an interesting thing today.

1. I pair to my module by entering a passkey
2. I can normally send data back and forth between my app and the module
3. From within my app I disconnect from the module and close my app.
4. On the module I change its passkey to a new value.
5. I reopen my app and can still exchange data. I do not need to go through pairing again. All security information exchanged by my phone and module when I first paired them (using the old passkey) seem to still be valid even after changing the PIN on the module.
6. I then close my app and unpair the device from Bluetooth settings.
7. After that I pair the two devices to make sure Passkey change was in fact accepted and surely enough it was. I can now only pair with the new PIN.

My surprise is that in point 5 above everything still worked even without updating the PIN also on my mobile phone. I plan on getting around this by calling removeBond() using reflection after I send the module a command to change PIN since this is enough for my particular use case. But if the PIN change could be triggered by something else then my phone this would not work.

My question is if this is normal. Bluetooth specs are quite long so I was hoping someone else knows this. I would imagine that after changing the passkey for a Bluetooth device all devices already paired with it will have to go through the pairing process again, this time with the new passkey. But steps above indicate this is not the case. Is this a bug on my Bluetooth module (Bluegiga WT12) or is this expected behaviour? Has Anyone encountered this before?

Thank you.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, Bluetooth specs are more friendly than I thought. I found my answer in this paragraph:

*The Bluetooth PIN is used to authenticate two Bluetooth devices (that have not
previously exchanged link keys) to each other and create a trusted relationship
between them. The PIN is used in the pairing procedure (see Section 11.2 on
page 241) to generate the initial link key that is used for further authentication.*

So passkey is not like a password in a router. It is just a sequence which both devices need to know when connecting so that one authenticates the other. Once they are sure they can trust each other they exchange link keys and those are used for future communication. Passkeys/PINs are then irrelevant.

I hope I understand this right.

Terribly sorry for posting too soon.

Cheers!